# My first haskell: best *inline* way to make a "natural language" listing of items? (like "1, 2, 3 and 4")

Tags: haskell

For my first line of Haskell I thought it'd be a nice case to produce a "natural listing" of items (of which the type supports `show` to get a string representation). By "natural listing" I mean summing up all items separated with `,` except the last one, which should read `and lastitem`. Ideally, I'd also like to not have a `,` before the "and".

To spice it up a bit (to show off the compactness of haskell), I wanted to have an "inline" solution, such that I can do

```
"My listing: " ++ ... mylist ... ++ ", that's our listing."
```

(Obviously for "production" making a function for that would be better in all ways, and allow for recursion naturally, but that's the whole point of my "inline" restriction for this exercise.)

For now I came up with:

```
main = do
    -- hello
    nicelist

nicelist = do
    let is = [1..10]
    putStrLn $ "My listing: " ++  concat [ a++b | (a,b) <- zip (map show is) (take (length is -1) $ repeat ", ") ++ [("and ", show $ last is)]] ++ ", that's our listing."
    let cs = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
    putStrLn $ "My listing: " ++  concat [ a++b | (a,b) <- zip (map show cs) (take (length cs -1) $ repeat ", ") ++ [("and ", show $ last cs)]] ++ ", that's our listing."
```

but this hardly seems optimal or elegant.

I'd love to hear your suggestions for a better solution.

EDIT:

Inspired by the comments and answer, I dropped the inline requirement and came up with the following, which seems pretty sleek. Would that be about as "haskellic" as we can get, or would there be improvements?

```
main = do
    putStrLn $ "My listing: " ++ myListing [1..10] ++ ", that's the list!"
    putStrLn $ "My listing: " ++ myListing ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"] ++ ", that's the list!"

myListing :: (Show a) => [a] -> String
myListing [] = "<nothing to list>"
myListing [x] = "only " ++ (show x)
myListing [x, y] = (show x) ++ " and " ++ (show y)
myListing (h:t) = (show h) ++ ", " ++ myListing t
```

Comment: Do you also need to handle any edge cases, like if there are 1 or 0 elements in the list?

Comment: @4castle goodpoint, I guess for the inline case that should be some literal indicator like "[]" ...

Comment: "I love my parents, Lady Gaga and Humpty Dumpty".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to state the rules for punctuating a list (without an Oxford comma) is this:

- Append a comma after every element except the last two
- Append “and” after the second-to-last element
- Leave the final element unchanged

This can be implemented by *zipping* the list with a “pattern” list containing the functions to perform the modifications, which repeats on one end. We want something like:

```
repeat (<> ",") <> [(<> " and"), id]
```

But of course this is just an infinite list of the comma function, so it will never get past the commas and on to the “and”. One solution is to reverse both the pattern list and the input list, and use `zipWith ($)` to combine them. But we can avoid the repeated reversals by using `foldr` to zip “in reverse” (actually, just right-associatively) from the *tail* end of the input. Then the result is simple:

```
punctuate :: [String] -> [String]
punctuate = zipBack
  $ [id, (<> " and")] <> repeat (<> ",")

zipBack :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
zipBack fs0 = fst . foldr
  (\ x (acc, f : fs) -> (f x : acc, fs))
  ([], fs0)
```

Example uses:

```
> test = putStrLn . unwords . punctuate . words

> test "this"
this

> test "this that"
this and that

> test "this that these"
this, that and these

> test "this that these those them"
this, that, these, those and them
```

There are several good ways to generalise this:

- `zipBack` is *partial*—it assumes the function list is infinite, or at least as long as the string list; consider different ways you could make it total, e.g. by modifying `fs0` or the lambda
- The punctuation and conjunction can be made into parameters, so you could use e.g. semicolons and “or”
- `zipBack` could work for more general types of lists, `Foldable` containers, and functions (i.e. `zipBackWith`)
- `String` could be replaced with an arbitrary `Semigroup` or `Monoid`

There’s also a cute *specialisation* possible—if you want to add the option to include an Oxford comma, its presence in the “pattern” (function list) depends on the length of the *final* list, because it should not be included for lists of 2 elements. Now, if only we could refer to the eventual result of a computation while computing it…

Comment: Thanks, that seems to tick the boxes I was hoping for: 1) "haskellic", 2) compact, 3) generic, 4) taught me both about a sleek use of `<>` and an apparently effective use of `foldr`. It only does a string of space separated words, but seems to be modifiable trivially to `(Show a) => [a]` (as you indicated in your 4th point).

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would write it:

```hs
import Data.List

niceShow' :: [String] -> String
niceShow' [] = "<empty>"
niceShow' [a] = a
niceShow' [a, b] = a ++ " and " ++ b
niceShow' ls = intercalate ", " (init ls) ++ ", and " ++ last ls

niceShow :: [String] -> String
niceShow ls =  "My listing: " ++ niceShow' ls ++ ", that's our listing."

niceList :: IO ()
nicelist = do
  putStrLn $ niceShow $ show <$> [1..10]
  putStrLn $ niceShow ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
```

Steps:

- Create `niceShow` to create your string
- Replace list comprehensions with good old function calls
- Know about [`intercalate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intercalate) and [`init`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:init)
- Add type signatures to top levels
- Format nicely

`niceShow` can only be inlined if you know the size of the list beforehand, otherwise, you'd be skipping the edge cases.

Comment: Yes, please. Squashing everything onto one line does not magically make it more compact.

Comment: @414owen: Thanks, I guess the inline requirement was a bit overboard ;)  I have added a solution I came up with, since I thought if I'd be using things like `intercalate` it probably uses some recursiveness in the background so I might as well "go vanilla" (back to basics) and do my own recursion. Would that be a correct characterisation? Or would one solution be more efficient (i.e. less costly) than the other?

Comment: @ppenguin `intercalate` is implemented with `intersperse` and `concat`. `intersperse` uses simple recursion, `concat` uses `foldr`. You can find these things by clicking on `source` on hackage.